# Download/Use a layer from Google Maps or Google Earth Pro

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-earth, kmz

Is there a way to download trails that are shown on Google Maps, or export a KMZ from Google Earth? I'd like to import these into ArcGIS Desktop.

Roads, boundaries, water bodies, etc. all have check boxes in the "Layers" pane of Google Earth but I can't find an associated layer for regular trails in Google Earth Pro.

Here are example screenshots of the trail layer I'd like to access, if that matters.

[image: Google Maps trail]

[image: Google Earth trail]

Comment: Use the extract tool on http://trails.dcnr.pa.gov/maptrails/index.html?trailid=472 for vector data (shapefile dxf kml etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that Google's layers are not typically exportable for other uses. You can save content you created as a KMZ but other layers are not exportable. In fact, small things like trails are frequently wrong. If you look closely at the Google Earth image you can see that their version of the 'trails' don't really line up very well with the ground disturbances that would be suggestive of actual trail location.

If you have access to QGIS or other GIS platform then perhaps you can bring up the aerial and digitize the trails. This will give you a higher accuracy product I am thinking.